# Find most common Object from a list

Tags: java, list, data-structures, performance, counting

Let's say I have a `List` of `Employee` Objects. The `Employee` Objects have a `getDepartment` method which returns a `Department` Object. I want to iterate through that list to find the department with the most `Employee`s (i.e. the `Department` Object returned most often from `getDepartment`). What is the fastest way to do this?

```
public class Employee{

   static allEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>();       

   int id;
   Department department;

   public Employee(int id, Department department){
     this.id = id;
     this.department = department;
     allEmployees.add(this);
   }

   public Department getDepartment(){
     return department;
   }

   public static List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){
      return allEmployees;
   }
}

public class Department{
   int id;
   String name;

   public Department(int id){
     this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName(){
     return name;
   }
}
```

If there's two departments with an equal number of employees it doesn't matter which is returned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a map of department id -> counts.

that way you get a collection of all the counts by id.  You can also maintain a max item that is a reference to the map entry with the highest count.

the algorithm would be something like:

1) Initialize a Map and a currentMax
2) loop through employees
3) for each employee, get its department id
4) do something like map.get(currentId)
   a) if the current count is null, initialize it
5) increment the count
6) if the incremented count is > currentMax, update currentMax

This algorithm will run in O(n); I don't think you can get any better than that.  Its space complexity is also O(n) because the number of counts is proportional to the size of the input.

If you wanted, you could create a class that uses composition (i.e. contains a Map and a List) and also manages keeping pointers to the Entry with the highest count.  That way this part of your functionality is properly encapsulated.  The stronger benefit of this approach is it allows you to maintain the count as you enter items into the list (you would proxy the methods that add employees to the list so they update the map counter).  Might be overkill though.

Comment: I thought about that, I was wondering if there was a map data structure in Java that keeps track of the highest Entry value. Do you know of any?

Comment: @adam, I don't know of any, although you can maintain a separate reference to the Map.Entry with the highest count.  Or you could write you own class to encapsulate that functionality.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but if you really wanted to do that you could just extend the HashMap class...that may be well beyond the scope of your program however.

Comment: @Adam - there is no such map data structure.  And it wouldn't make sense from a computational perspective to do that ... unless you *needed* to know the highest value *after every update*.

Comment: Could you post a `WORKING EXAMPLE` so that it is handy for further references

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vanilla Java 8 solution:

```
Employee.getAllEmployees()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

It passes through the list of employees at most twice. An equivalent solution using [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL), if you're willing to add a third-party dependency, is this:

```
Seq.seq(Employee.getAllEmployees())
   .grouped(Employee::getDepartment, Agg.count())
   .maxBy(Tuple2::v2)
   .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOλ)

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
Multiset<Department> departments = HashMultiset.create();
for (Employee employee : employees) {
  departments.add(employee.getDepartment());
}

Multiset.Entry<Department> max = null;
for (Multiset.Entry<Department> department : departments.entrySet()) {
  if (max == null || department.getCount() > max.getCount()) {
    max = department;
  }
}
```

You would need a correct implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` on `Department` for this to work.

There's also an issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=356) that mentions the possibility of creating a "leaderboard" type `Multiset` in the future that would maintain an order based on the count of each entry it contains.

Comment: And it is implemented since Guava 11: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html#copyHighestCountFirst%28com.google.common.collect.Multiset%29

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to count employees, it's relatively easy to make a map.

```
HashMap<Department, Integer> departmentCounter;
```

that maps Departments to the number of employees (you increment the count for every employee).  Alternatively, you can store the whole Employee in the map with a list:

```
HashMap<Department, List<Employee>> departmentCounter;
```

and look at the size of your lists instead.

Then you can look at the HashMap documentation if you don't know how to use the class:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Hint: you will need to use HashMap.keySet() to see which departments have been entered.

Comment: Umm ... I don't think this helps.  The problem is about finding the department(s) with the most employees.  Mapping from department ids to departments is not part of the problem, since each employee already has a reference to its department.

Comment: that's an improvement, but you don't need to keep lists of employees.  The problem just requires counts.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that, modulo == null and isEmpty checks:

```
public static <C> Multimap<Integer, C> getFrequencyMultimap(final Collection<C> collection,
    final Ordering<Integer> ordering) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Multimap<Integer, C> result = TreeMultimap.create(ordering, (Comparator<C>) Ordering.natural());
    for (C element : collection) {
        result.put(Collections.frequency(collection, element), element);
    }
    return result;
}

public static <C> Collection<C> getMostFrequentElements(final Collection<C> collection)       {
    Ordering<Integer> reverseIntegerOrdering = Ordering.natural().reverse();
    Multimap<Integer, C> frequencyMap = getFrequencyMultimap(collection, reverseIntegerOrdering);
    return frequencyMap.get(Iterables.getFirst(frequencyMap.keySet(), null));
}
```

There is also [CollectionUtils.getCardinalityMap()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#getCardinalityMap%28java.util.Collection%29) which will do the job of the first method, but this is more flexible and more guavish.

Just keep in mind that the C class should be well implemented, that is have equals(), hashCode() and implement Comparable.

This is how you can use it:

```
Collection<Dummy> result = LambdaUtils.getMostFrequentElements(list);
```

As a bonus, you can also get the less frequent element with a similar method, just, feed the first method with Ordering.natural() and do not reverse it.